# SQL Server Function Call CLR to sleep

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, function, clr

For testing I need to artificially create a slow SQL statement.
I have managed to achieve this on Oracle/Java (details below), but am struggling to achieve the same in T-SQL/VB.Net/SQLServer.

The idea is to have a function which simply sleeps for a few (say 5) seconds and returns a dummy value.

I have tried (as an alternative) to use the 'waitfor' T-SQL, but this isn't allowed in FUNCTIONS (side-effects apparently); so I'm thinking (apart from creating vast tables, or spinning nested empty loops) the best way to do this is via CLR objects....

Can somebody provide some simple steps to achieve this ?

Here's the steps I following in Oracle:
First Create a Java Class to do the sleeping:

```
package com.monojohnny;
public class sleepy {
            public static String sleep()  {
                int seconds=5;
                try {
                        Thread.sleep(seconds * 1000);
                }
                catch(Exception e) { ; }
                return "Finished Sleeping for "+Integer.toString(seconds)+" seconds.";

            }
}
```

Secondly , compile it, with something like:

```
javac -source 1.4 -target 1.4 com/monojohnny/sleepy.java
```

Thirdly, load the resultant .class file into the Oracle DB:

```
call loadjava -user %username%/%password% com\monojohnny\sleepy.class
```

Lastly, create a PL/SQL Function to call the class's method:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sleepy RETURN VARCHAR2
            AS LANGUAGE JAVA
            NAME 'com.monojohnny.sleepy.sleep() return java.lang.String';
    /
    show errors
    quit;
```

And this is the result of testing the function:

```
SQL> select sleepy from dual;
Finished Sleeping for 5 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

check out this link:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/e8f32710-9424-48a8-8de1-523457ea291f

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.wait()
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @i INT = (
    SELECT TOP 1 1 
    FROM OPENQUERY(DW, 'waitfor delay ''00:00:05.000'' select 1 as n')
);

RETURN 1;
END;
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for this - but What is 'DW' ? I can't get this to work on my SQL Server Express Instance ? Error is : Msg 7202, Level 11, State 2, Procedure wait, Line 7
Could not find server 'DW' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.

Comment: "DW" is a linked server name.  Run "sp_linkedservers" to see if you have any configured.  You won't have "DW" but you will likely have others.

Comment: Hi Kevin - but what is the purpose of the Linked Server ? I'm trying to avoid any additional changes to the DB - other than creating a function - and possibly uploading a .NET program really...

Comment: Actually this link : http://sqlserverplanet.com/dba/local-linked-server allowed me to add a 'dummy' local 'linked server'...

Comment: And it worked - I'm leaving the question open for a wee while - I'm still interested in the CLR approach - but I'll come back and accept as the accepted answer if I don't receive any CLR-based solutions. Thanks for the help on this.